# PHP - setcookie(); not working ( Cannot modify header information - headers already sent )

Tags: php, setcookie

I am getting this error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /removed/loginform.php:2) in /removed/loginform.php on line 24

I understand that I am getting the error when I try to set a cookie, and it's because setcookie can't have any output before it... the problem is, there is no output before it (At least from what I can see). It is saying that "< ?php" is a header, and I don't understand that. If setcookie can only be used in PHP and < ?php is a header, how is it even possible to use setcookie without getting this header error?

My code:

```
<!--Database Connections-->
<?php include "../../includes/dbpractice_con.php"; ?>

<?php 

//Declare variables
$username = "";
$password = "";
$message = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { //Retrieve from form when submit is clicked.

    //Escape to prevent SQL injection.
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);

    $check = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
    $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($check);

    if ($rowCount == 1) {

        $cookieExpiration = time() + 757368000; //1 year

        setcookie("username", $username, $cookieExpiration);

    } else {
        $message = "Invalid username or password. <br/>Don't have an account? Click <a href=\"registerform.php\">here</a> to register.<br/><br/>";
    }

}


?>

<html>
```

Comment: @VBCPP It is the same problem, but the question you referenced doesn't have any details explaining how the problem was caused there in the first place.

Comment: you can't have anything in front of `<?php`, in any script called, or output anything prior to `setcookie()` call. sometimes you can't even call (include, require) UTF-8 scripts because they create BOM output. Working with output buffering is always good idea.

Comment: What is the complete output and include the contents of "../../includes/dbpractice_con.php" into your question, since this might contain code that may cause the problem.

Comment: @Irdrah Contents of dbpractice_con.php: <?php
//If the page shows nothing, the connection was successful.

define("HOST", "xxx");
define("USERNAME", "xxx");
define("PASSWORD", "xxx");
define("DATABASE", "xxx");

$connection=mysqli_connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>

Comment: @mega well that's still not including it into then question, but it seems that your question has ben solved already, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Irdah, it always matters, because a lot of people face same problem and Q&As here help them getting clues to find solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<!--Database Connections-->` is HTML output, even if it is just a comment. Remove that and try again.

**EDIT:**
There is also a space between the PHP blocks. Try putting the include in the main PHP block.

Comment: PHP doesn't know what it is, it just sees text out of the `<?php ?>` tags, so it sends it as output.

Comment: Didn't work. Still getting the same error.

Comment: For me this error is almost always a space or carriage return that is outputted before any attempt by php to write or change the response header.

Comment: Thanks. I put the include in the main PHP block and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Generally that means you have sent something to client prior to `setcookie()` call.

Do simple test:

```
<?php

  ob_start();
  include "../../includes/dbpractice_con.php"; ?>

  # ... rest of your code... #
```

and before setcookie() call add line

```
ob_get_clean();
```

just to be sure that no output was made earlier.

Anything outside of `<?php ?>` is HTML and is sent to user. So this

```
<!--Database Connections-->
<?php include "../../includes/dbpractice_con.php"; ?>
```

outputs `<!--Database Connections-->` as HTML comment. Another possible output is here

```
<?php include "../../includes/dbpractice_con.php"; ?>

<?php ...
```

at least you have new line character between two PHP tags, which is also unwanted output.

You can't have anything to echo, print_r, var_dump data before cookieset() call, check manually for these functions.

Always check all included scripts (with include, require, etc).

**BE SURE THEY START WITH `<?php` WITH NOTHING BEFORE and END WITH `?>` FOLLOWING NOTHING.**

this is good example:

```
<?php
  // some lines
?>
```

these aren't

```
something<?php ?>
```

or

```
<?php ?>something
```

or

```
<?php  ?>
```

(if file has been saved as UTF-8).

Look at your **dbpractice_con.php**, check is it saved as ANSI (from notepad check with save as dialog), be sure that everything is between  and no one character is before and after the tags. Don't use multiple  tags in same script because it increases risk of unwanted output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
// Database connections
include "../../includes/dbpractice_con.php";

//Declare variables
// ... proceed with code ...
```

If this doesn't work then the problem is probably in `dbpractice_con.php`